# Logging in frontend giving 500 Internal Server Error in magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9

Whenever a customer is placing an order using credit card, then after that if the customer is trying to log-in or click on any of the top-link like 'checkout', 'account', then it is getting `500 Internal Server Error`.
It is majorly happening for pages with https

My PHP error log is filing this:

> [26-Feb-2016 09:38:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function
>   setFinalPrice() on a non-object in
>   /www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php
>   on line 89

Can anyone please suggest something?
It is very important for me to make it working otherwise live orders are blocked for customers

Comment: @Marius: I saw a similar answer to the question I have.
Can you please help me!
In my magento application, suddenly if customer once placed order, then he is unable to access any page with https and error log says as mentioned in the question.
Can you please tell me a way to debug?

Comment: This helped me to get to the solution:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63121/quote-with-no-items-add-to-cart-error